# Employee - net salary

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Write JUnit test class named  "EmployeeTest" to test the method calNetPay in the given Employee Class

Employee.java

public class Employee {

```
private int eid;

private String name;

private double salary;

private double pfper;

public Employee(int eid, String name, double salary, double pfper) {

    super();

    this.eid = eid;

    this.name = name;

    this.salary = salary;

    this.pfper = pfper;

}

public double calNetPay(){

    if(pfper <= 5){

        return salary;

    } else {

        return salary-salary*(pfper/100);

    }

}
```

}

please tell me to do this question I tried some way but that do not fulfill the requirements.

Comment: are you willing to use RAD tools like IntellJ or Eclipse or Maven or Gradle ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show us what you have tried. We can help you understand what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**EmployeeTest**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class EmployeeTest {
    Employee emp = null;
    
    @Test
    public void testCalNetPay() {
        emp = new Employee(101,"xyz",5000.0,3);
        double netPay = emp.calNetPay();
        assertEquals(5000.0,netPay,0.0);
        
        emp = new Employee(102,"abc",1000.0,6);
        netPay = emp.calNetPay();
        assertEquals(940.0,netPay,0.0);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeMain**

```
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;


public class EmployeeMain {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(EmployeeTest.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

This should work, hope it helps.